# How to map from characters to numbers in clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

How to map from characters to numbers in clojure?

Like I have a function:

```
(defn letter [c]
(str (last c)))
```

If I input: user => (letter "4R"), then I want the output as R. How to map the string value "R" to R?

Comment: Where is the output to appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R is not a number. A literal R in Clojure is a symbol. You can make symbols from strings using `symbol` - i.e. `(symbol "R") => R`

As @noisesmith said, characters (written as `\R`, for example) are also not numbers in Clojure/Java. It's not completely clear what you're asking, so if this isn't helpful please expand your question a little more - for instance, explain what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to know this : (symbol "R") :)

Answer (score 5):

In the jvm, a character is not a number.

```
user> (last "4R")
\R
user> (type (last "4R"))
java.lang.Character
```

It is easy to make a number out of one though.

```
user> (int (last "4R"))
82
```

In clojurescript there is no character datatype, so the approach is different

```
cljs.user=> (.charCodeAt (last "4R") 0)
82
```

Comment: What is the 82? I just want the output R. Right now it is giving "R".

Comment: In clojure, `\R` is the closest you will ever get. In clojurescript, there is no such thing. The `symbol` `R` will print in the way you want, but it is not a character.

Comment: Also, your title is "how to map from characters to numbers", and the character R maps to the number 82.